# Writing to a text file gives me strange results

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

So Im trying to get a variable to be written into a text file, but I keep getting eastern symbols inside the file.

Heres my code:

```
.model small          
.stack 100
.data 
        Num1 DB 98     ;input  

        filename db "test.txt",0
        handler dw ?   
        text db "The two numbers from input are:  $" 


.code
START:          
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax     

        ;FILE
        ;create file
        MOV  ah, 3ch
        MOV  cx, 0
        MOV  dx, offset filename
        INT  21h  

        ;file handler
        MOV handler, Ax

        ;write string
        MOV ah, 40h
        MOV Bx, handler
        MOV Cx, 50  ;string length
        MOV Dx, offset Num1
        INT 21h

        MOV Ax, 4c00h
        INT 21h



    end start
```

And the result in my text file is:

> b整瑳琮瑸Ԁ吀敨琠潷渠浵敢獲映潲⁭湩異⁴牡㩥†$ី

I don't understand why this happens. I didn't see most of these symbols in the ascii lists either. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Your variable is 1 byte but you are writing 50. Also your number is in binary. The ascii code of `b` is `98` so that's your first character correctly. Presumably whatever program you used to display the file thought it was utf8 encoded due to the binary stuff in it. If you view it as plain ascii you should also see your `filename` and `text` in there.

Comment: @Jester I made it 50 because I want to add more numbers in the future, so Im just testing with this simpler kind of code. Also do you know any way to tell it to make it in ascii and not utf8? Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: There's a possibility your code is fine but whatever program is showing you the file is interpreting the text as UTF-16